# ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I m facing the issue on Flask, when I try to import flask

```
from flask import Flask
```

and it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path to project>\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
  File "<path to project>\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (<path to project>\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py)
```

I confirmed that flask is on the latest version and markupsafe is installed
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling
The issue started after reinstalling pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jinja2.Markup` was removed in version 3.1.0; see the changelog: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-1-0

It should be imported directly from the `markupsafe` package instead, which I believe was split off from Jinja as a separate package some time ago.